# asp mvc error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object when validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]   
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]CustomerInfo customerinfo)

{

   if (customerinfo.FirstName.Trim().Length == 0)
       ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "First name is required.");
   if (customerinfo.LastName.Trim().Length == 0)
       ModelState.AddModelError("LastName", "Last name is required.");
   if (customerinfo.Phone.Length > 0 && !Regex.IsMatch(customerinfo.Phone, @"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}"))
       ModelState.AddModelError("Phone", "Invalid phone number.");
   if (customerinfo.Email.Length > 0 && !Regex.IsMatch(customerinfo.Email, @"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$"))
       ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Invalid email address.");
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       return View();
   try
   {
        BLL.Customer customer = new BLL.Customer();
        customer.CreateCustomer(customerinfo);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: `customerinfo` is null,so u r getting that exception..

Comment: Have you seen the Data Annotation Validation Attributes? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx This looks like a perfect use case for them

Comment: also Data Annotation Validation Attributes not worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really step through and indicate where exactly it fails. Most likely this would tell you enough to fix the problem yourself. In particular, look at the line-number; that will take you to the line that is failing.

However, my guess is simply that one of `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Phone` or `Email` is `null` (which is the default for strings, so entirely expected) - or that `customerinfo` *itself* is null.

Changing to

```
if (customerinfo.FirstName == null || customerinfo.FirstName.Trim().Length == 0)
   ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "First name is required.");
```

(etc) will probably fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot the validation is Working now

Comment: That check is what string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace) is for *grin* So you could simply with

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customerinfo.FirstName))
   ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "First name is required.");